# PATH details different in different terminal windows

Tags: command-line, paths

I have added a particular path to `PATH` and I am able to see that it has been added when I `echo` it, but when I `echo $PATH` in another window I cannot see that path I recently added. I am not sure why I am not able to see it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables don't escape the shell they're set in. So unless you add it to your `~/.bashrc`, no other terminals will see the extra entry in `$PATH`

Comment: how can I add it to my `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: `gedit ~/.bashrc` and add a line `export VARIABLE-NAME=VALUE`

Comment: Got it thanks. and I also need to `source ~/.bashrc` which I was missing out

Comment: I don't think you need `source ~/.bashrc`, as bashrc is executed by default.

Comment: Nope had to `source` it and it worked. Was not working without it

Comment: That is very strange. putting `source` inside the `~/.bashrc` to include `~/.bashrc`... paradox.

Comment: inside?? I think the reason was because the terminal windows were already open and change in `~/.bashrc` in one terminal window was probably not read in other terminal windows.